# ADB Mount/Unmount SD Card in Android

Tags: android, adb, android-sdcard, mount

I'm triying to umount/mount the SD Card in my Android device. For that, I'm running ADB as root.

Mount usage is as follows:

```
mount [-r] [-w] -[-o options] [-t type] device directory.
```

So I'm trying to do:

mount [DEVICE] /storage/extsd

The problem is that I can't understand what I should put in [DEVICE] field.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

to umount:
umount /mnt/shell/emulated/

to mount:
/system/bin/sdcard -l -t4 /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated 1023 1023 &

to test:
ls /mnt/shell/emulated/0 
mount | grep fuse

ps. that's is on my device - I use freescale

lg and motorola has it like this
/system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -l /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated
/system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -l /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated
it's all emulated sdcard from /data/media/